# How to compile C program with code::blocks and Cygwin

Tags: c, cygwin

I am trying to compile a toy C program named hello.c using Code::Blocks and Cygwin. I have both programs installed on my C drive but for some reason Code::Blocks can't find Cygwin. I believe I have set Cygwin as my default compiler on the Code::Blocks settings (see snapshot), however, the exe file is never created after I try to compile. I also tried the cmd screen with no luck.
This is the toy hello.c program that I am trying to create with Cygwin:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    printf("hello, world\n");
}
```

Questions: Does Cygwin needs to be in the PATH?

Do I need something in the Code::Blocks settings?

[image]

Comment: Cygwin is not a c compiler, you need to set the path to your compilers.

Comment: As you set the settings, the compiler executable "gcc.exe" is expected in "C:\Cygwin\bin". Did you check this? -- Additionally, you can add this path (temporarily) to your `PATH` and try to compiler from the command line, just to check that its installation is OK.